# Error while executing the following query using temporary columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I know this looks a bit simple but i have been getting this error while executing this query:

```
SELECT 'NOC Service Request Acknowledgement - All severities' AS [Problem_Type_Name(Parent) Category]
,[Job_ticket_id]
,CASE WHEN (case when [Escalated to Resolved time] is null then (ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) + ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0)- ISNULL([hold time],0)) else (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) - ISNULL([hold time],0)) end) <0THEN 0 ELSE (case when [Escalated to Resolved time] is null then (ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) + ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0)- ISNULL([hold time],0)) else (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) - ISNULL([hold time],0)) end)  END AS JobTime
,[Time to Accept SLA]
,[Report_Date]
,[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]
,[Assigned Tech]
,[PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME]
,[Close_Date]
,[NAME]
,[Ticket Status]
,[Escalated to Closed time]
,[Escalated to Resolved time]
,[Hold Time]
,case when String_value in ('Warning' ,'Critical') then String_value else null end  as 'String_value'
,[PROBLEM_TYPE_ID]
FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE_Category
join ticket_custom_field custom1 on custom1.entity_id = job_ticket_id
join custom_field_definition custom_definition1 on custom_definition1.id=custom1.definition_id  
WHERE [Problem_Type_Name(Parent) Category] IN ('NOC Service Request Acknowledgement - Urgent','NOC Service Request Acknowledgement - High',
'NOC Service Request Acknowledgement - Medium','NOC Service Request Acknowledgement - Low')
```

In this query, [Problem_Type_Name(Parent) Category] is column in which groups of tickets are inserted according to the conditions defined and are given a group name like 'NOC Service Request Acknowledgement - Urgent','NOC Service Request Acknowledgement - High','NOC Service Request Acknowledgement - Medium','NOC Service Request Acknowledgement - Low'.
it seems like there is something wrong with my query becuase the above code gives an error at the Where condition.

Comment: Include the error you get. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

[Problem_Type_Name(Parent) Category]

is not a column to apply where